# Best practice accessing Q_PROPERTY in qml from another thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, qml, thread-safety

I have a larger project that crashes randomly after a few hours. I believe it is due to qml accessing `Q_PROPERTY` in my C++ QObject, where the `Q_PROPERTY` is set in another thread, causing a data race.

I have a simple toy project [here](https://github.com/XDSFyP/TestQPropertyThreading/tree/c4758df8b6cca0a8e20c2fa1c4d5fca311dbfb9d). In it `main.qml` has a label that accesses a QProperty `test.testChild.time`. `test.testChild.time` is set in another thread when a QTimer expires and calls `Test::timerExpired()`. `Test::timerExpired()` has a `QThread::usleep(100000)` to simulate a long operation. When I comment the `moveToThread(&m_workerThread)` line below, the ui is much less responsive than before but everything is in the same thread so I believe  data race cannot occur. If I don't comment `moveToThread(&m_workerThread)` and have `timer.setInterval(0)`, the ui is very responsive but a crash occurs usually within a few minutes on my Ubuntu VM.

The code below is a section from test.cpp in my simple toy project [here](https://github.com/XDSFyP/TestQPropertyThreading/tree/c4758df8b6cca0a8e20c2fa1c4d5fca311dbfb9d)

```
Test::Test(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
//  , testChild(this) // uncommenting this line will cause testChild to move to m_workerThread
{
    uiThread = QThread::currentThreadId();

    // move this object to a separate thread so does not interrupt UI thread
    moveToThread(&m_workerThread); // commenting this line will make test::timerExpired() run on UI thread and slow down UI

    timer.setInterval(0); // with interval 0, more likely to seg fault due to data race

    connect(&timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(timerExpired()));
    connect(&m_workerThread, SIGNAL(started()), &timer, SLOT(start()));
    m_workerThread.start();
}

void Test::timerExpired()
{
    if (uiThread == QThread::currentThreadId())
        qCritical() << "timerExpired() Controller thread is same as UI thread";

    QMutexLocker locker(&mutex);// prevent UI thread from accessing objects below while they update with a QMutexLocker

    QString time;

    time = QDateTime::currentDateTime().toString("hh:mm:ss.zzz");

    QThread::usleep(100000); // long operation

    setTime(time);
    testChild.setTime(time);
}
```

How can I safely have two threads, one for qml and another for long operations, while qml can access QProperties that update in the long operations thread?

Comment: the code is incomplete. what is `setTime()` and `testChild`? How do you access QML?

Comment: It's not easy to reproduce the problem with this test program. It happened to me only once and after 15 minutes. Also is unknown why it crashed as I can see there are large memory leaks - after killing the core dump file size is larger the longer the app runs. Also running under valgrind shows lot of memory still reachable. It may be due to timer flooding the slot - timer expiring in no time and slot working for 100000+us. To fix the suspected race condition you could try to set time from Test by emitting signal to slot which would do it in UI thread.

Comment: @folibis I have more clearly described where the rest of the code can be found. I thought  it might be easier if others code download my simple project rather than have lots of code in the question.

Comment: @doqtor That is the exact issue I'm having and I have found it very hard to reproduce unless I set the timer interval to 0. I think you are right, I will need to emit a signal to a class in the UI thread. This class in the UI thread will then hold the QProperties so data race cannot happen (as far as I know).

Comment: @doqtor Someone has described emitting a signal to a second class in the UI [here](https://forum.qt.io/topic/30169/qt-5-1-qml-property-through-threads/5)

Comment: @doqtor By the way, commenting out the `QThread::usleep(100000); // long operation` will make the example crash a lot faster, within minutes on Windows (compared to my Ubuntu VM)

Answer (score 0):

I believe I have solved this using a model so the QML can safely communicate with the another thread.

The model is instantiated in the UI thread. The model receives data using signals and slots from the other thread (which is threadsafe). The model has QProperties that QML can interface with. When the model receives new data from another thread, QProperties are updated and QML receives new data.

The project is [here](https://github.com/XDSFyP/TestQPropertyThreading/tree/threadsafe) but is also included below

TestQPropertyThread.pro

```
QT += quick

CONFIG += c++11

DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS

QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -g -Wall -Werror

SOURCES += \
        controller.cpp \
        controllerchild.cpp \
        main.cpp \
        model.cpp

RESOURCES += qml.qrc

HEADERS += \
    controller.h \
    controllerchild.h \
    model.h
```

main.cpp

```
#include "controller.h"
#include "model.h"

#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QQmlContext>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);

    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;

    Controller test;
    Model model(test);

    engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty(QStringLiteral("model"), &model);

    const QUrl url(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml"));
    QObject::connect(&engine, &QQmlApplicationEngine::objectCreated,
                     &app, [url](QObject *obj, const QUrl &objUrl) {
        if (!obj && url == objUrl)
            QCoreApplication::exit(-1);
    }, Qt::QueuedConnection);
    engine.load(url);

    return app.exec();
}
```

controller.cpp

```
#include "controller.h"

Controller::Controller(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent), testChild(this), timer(this) // testChild to move to m_workerThread
{
    uiThread = QThread::currentThreadId();

    // move this object to a separate thread so does not interrupt UI thread
    moveToThread(&m_workerThread); // commenting this line will make test::timerExpired() run on UI thread and slow down UI

    timer.setInterval(0); // with interval 0, more likely to seg fault due to data race

    connect(&timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(timerExpired()));
    connect(&m_workerThread, SIGNAL(started()), &timer, SLOT(start()));
    m_workerThread.start();
}

void Controller::timerExpired()
{
    if (uiThread == QThread::currentThreadId())
        qCritical() << "Controller::timerExpired() Controller thread is same as UI thread";

    // prevent UI thread from accessing objects below while they update with a QMutexLocker
    QMutexLocker locker(&mutex);

    QString time;

    time = QDateTime::currentDateTime().toString("hh:mm:ss.zzz");
    qDebug() << "Controller::timerExpired()" << time; // this can impact preformance when usleep is commented out
    QThread::usleep(100000); // long operation

    testChild.setTime(time);
}
```

controller.h

```
#ifndef TEST_H
#define TEST_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QTimer>
#include <QThread>
#include <QMutex>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QDateTime>
#include "controllerchild.h"

class Controller : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit Controller(QObject *parent = nullptr);

    ControllerChild testChild;

public slots:
    void timerExpired();

private:
    QTimer timer;
    QThread m_workerThread;
    Qt::HANDLE uiThread;
    QMutex mutex;
};

#endif // TEST_H
```

controllerchild.cpp

```
#include "controllerchild.h"

ControllerChild::ControllerChild(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{

}

void ControllerChild::setTime(const QString &value)
{
    time = value;
    emit timeChanged(time);
}

void ControllerChild::onButtonPress(const QString &value)
{
    qDebug() << "ControllerChild::onButtonPress()" << value << QThread::currentThreadId() << QDateTime::currentDateTime().toString("hh:mm:ss.zzz");
    emit onBoolChanged(value); // send value back to UI label
}
```

controllerchild.h

```
#ifndef TESTCHILD_H
#define TESTCHILD_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QThread>
#include <QDateTime>

class ControllerChild : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit ControllerChild(QObject *parent = nullptr);

    void setTime(const QString &value);

public slots:
    void onButtonPress(const QString &value);

signals:
    void timeChanged(const QString &value);
    void onBoolChanged(QString value);

private:
    QString time;

};

#endif // TESTCHILD_H
```

model.cpp

```
#include "model.h"

Model::Model(Controller &test, QObject *parent) : QObject(parent), test(test)
{
    connect(&test.testChild, &ControllerChild::timeChanged, this, [=](const QString &time){ this->setTime(time); });
    connect(this, &Model::onButtonPressChanged, &test.testChild, &ControllerChild::onButtonPress);
    connect(&test.testChild, &ControllerChild::onBoolChanged, this, [=](const QString &value){ this->setBoolValue(value); });
}

QString Model::getTime() const
{
    //    return QString("test Child %1").arg(time);
    return time;
}

void Model::setTime(const QString &value)
{
    time = value;
    emit timeChanged();
}

void Model::onButtonPress(const QString &value)
{
    qDebug() << "Model::onButtonPress()" << value << QThread::currentThreadId() << QDateTime::currentDateTime().toString("hh:mm:ss.zzz");
    emit onButtonPressChanged(value);
}

void Model::onBool(const QString &value)
{
    qDebug() << "Model::onBool()" << value << QThread::currentThreadId() << QDateTime::currentDateTime().toString("hh:mm:ss.zzz");
    emit onBoolChanged(value);
}

void Model::setBoolValue(const QString &value)
{
    boolValue = value;
    qDebug() << "Model::setBoolValue()" << value << QThread::currentThreadId() << QDateTime::currentDateTime().toString("hh:mm:ss.zzz");
    emit onBoolChanged(value);
}
```

model.h

```
#ifndef MODEL_H
#define MODEL_H

#include <QObject>

#include "controller.h"

class Model : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

    Q_PROPERTY(QString time READ getTime WRITE setTime NOTIFY timeChanged)
    Q_PROPERTY(QString boolValue MEMBER boolValue NOTIFY onBoolChanged)
public:
    explicit Model(Controller &test, QObject *parent = nullptr);

    QString getTime() const;
    void setTime(const QString &value);

    void setBoolValue(const QString &value);

public slots:
    void onButtonPress(const QString &value);
    void onBool(const QString &value);

signals:
    void timeChanged();
    void onButtonPressChanged(const QString &value);
    void onBoolChanged(const QString &value);

private:
    QString time;
    Controller &test;
    QString boolValue;
};

#endif // MODEL_H
```

main.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.12

import QtQuick.Controls 2.12

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    Label {
        id: time1
        text: model.time
    }

    BusyIndicator {
        id: busyIndicator
        x: 0
        y: 23
    }

    PathView {
        id: pathView
        x: 0
        y: 135
        width: 640
        height: 130
        delegate: Column {
            spacing: 5
            Rectangle {
                width: 40
                height: 40
                color: colorCode
                anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
            }

            Text {
                x: 5
                text: name
                anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
                font.bold: true
            }
        }
        path: Path {
            startY: 100
            startX: 120
            PathQuad {
                x: 120
                y: 25
                controlY: 75
                controlX: 260
            }

            PathQuad {
                x: 120
                y: 100
                controlY: 75
                controlX: -20
            }
        }
        model: ListModel {
            ListElement {
                name: "Grey"
                colorCode: "grey"
            }

            ListElement {
                name: "Red"
                colorCode: "red"
            }

            ListElement {
                name: "Blue"
                colorCode: "blue"
            }

            ListElement {
                name: "Green"
                colorCode: "green"
            }
        }
    }

    Button {
        id: button
        x: 0
        y: 271
        text: qsTr("Press me!!")
        checkable: true
        onToggled: model.onButtonPress(button.checked)
    }

    Label {
        id: label
        x: 106
        y: 294
        text: model.boolValue
    }


}
```